# I need query to return all document that contains a specific string in list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, djongo

I need to perform a **django query** to return all document that contains a specific string `"amazon"` in the list, and this list is stored in a dict. 
The field is  a dict and each key in the dictionary contain a list type.

This sample of my document:

```
{
    "collector_id" : 80,
    "market_info" : {
        "market_name_list" : [ 
            "amazon", 
            "souq"
        ],
        "key_2" : [
            "item1_in_list",
            "item2_in_list",
            "item3_in_list"
        ]
    }
}
```

market_info is DictField.

I tried a lot of queries but all of them failed.

```
query_set = myModel.objects.filter(market_info__contains= 
{'market_name_list': ['amazon']})
```

This is my Model:

```
from djongo import models as db

class info(db.Model):
    collector = db.ForeignKey(Collector, null=True,                   
              on_delete=db.SET_NULL)
    market_info = db.DictField(default={'market_name_list': [],
                                        'search_for_list': []
                                       })
```

Comment: can you show your `model`?
`expected input` and `expected output`?

Comment: I added my model. What do you mean by expected input and output?

Comment: Is the list always in `key_2`?

Comment: @CarlBrubaker Yes, I stored a list for each key in the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

```
found = []
for i in info.objects.all():
    for m in i.market_info:
        if market_info[m] == 'string':
           found.append(i)
```

Comment: I will try this... but what about the performance if I have more than 20K documents?

Comment: You have to get through all of the data some how. There might be faster methods than this, but you might want to think about rewriting how the data is handled.

Comment: Thank you... it's work. I really hope there is a query doing that. I will wait one day for another answer, if there is no answerI will accept your answer.

Comment: I removed the second  `for` because I ready know any key I will search into it, and update if to `if  'amazon' in i.market_info['market_name_list']:`Thank you :)

Comment: Just remember that using `in` will also give you `fooamazonbar` in your results

Comment: Sorry but what is `fooamazonbar` ? I always see `foo` but I don't know it.

Comment: `foobar` is just a example thing, like a `dict = {'foo': 'bar'}`. Using `in` instead of `==` expands your results. `'amazon'` **is** `in` `'amazonriver'`, `'my_amazon'`, `'aaamazonnnn'`, `'ihateamazon'`. If you only want results that have a list item `'amazon'`, you should use `==` not `in`.